# Understanding Unity-UI Layout Element - Mininum and Preferred Size

Tags: unity, ui-design, unity-ui, aspect-ratio

I have been working with Unity for some time, and I am trying to get a better understand of the UI system.

I am a mobile developer and am redesigning the UI but I am unable to achieve what I want.

My game is in portrait mode and I have a panel. I want the panel to have a maximum width of 1080 pixels. In cases where the panel doesn't fit on the screen because the aspect ratio is less (like the new iPhone X), I want it to shrink it a bit with a minimum width of 700 pixels. In the case that the screen is larger than 1080p (like the iPad Pro) I want the panel to have the maximum size.

Here are visuals of what I want to achieve:

Nexus 6P ( 1080x1920)

[image: Layout on Nexus 6P]

iPhone X(1125x2436)

[image: Layout on iPhone X]

iPad pro (2048x2732)

[image: Layout on iPad Pro]

I have been playing with `Layout Element` and `Content Size Fitter` components without success.

If I set the min width size to 700 pixels and preferred size to 1080 pixels nothing happens (even after setting flexible width.)

If I set the `Content Size Fitter` to the preferred size it just always reverts to the preferred size. The same thing happens with min.

How do these components work, and how I can achieve the desired effect?

Canvas configuration:

[image: canvas confifuration in inspector]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be accomplished with the `ContentSizeFitter` and `LayoutElement` components. Instead, you will need a custom script that sniffs the device's screen size and computes the aspect ratio and adjusts the `RectTransform` accordingly.

Fortunately this is quite simple. Here is a demo to show how this can be done. For this example we have a `Canvas` gameobject with a `Panel` child. This panel will be the target of our scaling.

[image: minimal setup]

The canvas' `CanvasScaler` component can be set to any of the three *UIScaleModes* -- all work. The panel's `RectTransform` anchor preset should be set to *stretch/stretch* and the top, bottom, left and right values should all be set to zero to have the panel fill the canvas by default.

[image: anchor presets]
[image: panel values in inspector]

For demo purposes, the script is attached to an empty gameobject. Also for demo purposes, the scaling routine runs in the `Update` loop -- something you would obviously never want to do in a real application. Here's the script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AspectRatioDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform panel;
    public float maxAspectRatio = 1080f / 1920f; // example: Nexus 6P

    // routine shown in Update for demo purposes, obviously you would only do this once...
    void Update()
    {
        float currentAspectRatio = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;
        if(currentAspectRatio > maxAspectRatio)
        {
            float padding = (currentAspectRatio - maxAspectRatio)/2f;
            if(padding > .5f)
            {
                Debug.LogError("unsupported aspect ratio"); //addition logic required to support landscape mode
                return;
            }
            panel.anchorMax = new Vector2(1.0f - padding, 1.0f);
            panel.anchorMin = new Vector2(padding, 0);
        }
        else // this is only necessary if panel was previously resized
        {
            panel.anchorMax = Vector2.one;
            panel.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

`maxAspectRatio` represents the widest aspect you'll allow before padding the panel's margins. By default I have it set to 1080/1920 (.5625). The routine checks whether the actual aspect ratio exceeds this by dividing `Screen.width` by `Screen.Height`. If not, it does nothing. If it does, it computes a padding value. (Note the if the computed padding value is greater than .5 we're talking about a device in landcape mode which is unexpected and unsupported here.) Finally the code adjusts the anchors to create the padding.

[image: GIF Demo]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem using Anchors. Set your anchor of parent panel to stretch.

below I attached a screenshot to make you understand what I am saying,

[image: You can found this tool in Unity's Transform component]

> You can found this tool in Unity UI's Rect Transform component where you have to click on the icon and it pops up the attached screenshot.

Now press Alt + Shift (Alt to set position and Shift to set pivot of the object). You will achieve the result you wanted by pressing both alt and shift together and select right one on the downside (last one).

you can learn or read more about anchor point in this unity doc :

> [Setting UI for multiple screen resolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, this will make the RectTransform to scale always at the same ratio. I want to scale it with a maximum and a minimuim

Comment: As per my understanding, it scales to your screen size, even i use this method to scale my UI according to screen size, i think you understand it in wrong manner. however, i will explain here again that when you press Alt with shift and holding both key when you click the last anchor preset it sets your anchors at the corner and it allows you to strecth your screen.

Comment: As you has stated it scales with screen size, but it don't limit the min size or max size, it just scale it, so If you have a panel with a width of 100. and you want to limit the width to a maximum of 200, if there is a screen 3x times larger the width will be 300, instead of 200. I want to give a maximum width